# A strange error with tf.cast

Tags: tensorflow

When I was doing the homework of Deeplearning, I met a strange error with tf.cast, just like this:

```
test_1 = tf.cast(tf.square(2.0*300*400*64), tf.float32)
test_2 = tf.cast(tf.square(2*300*400*64), tf.float32)
test_3 = tf.cast(235929600000000, tf.float32)
sess.run([test_1, test_2, test_3])
```

However, I got the result as this:

```
[235929600000000.0, -1543503900.0, 235929600000000.0]
```

I think this may be causes by the difference number of bits of float and int. Can someone give the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.square(2*300*400*64)` is`(2^13 x 3^1 x 5^4)^2` Then

```
2^26 x 3^2 x 5^8 > 2^26 x 3^2 x 2^17
                 = 2^43 + 3^2
```

And int32 can only represent numbers up to `2^32`. Try using int64 or uint64 instead:

```
import numpy as np
test_2 = tf.cast(tf.square(np.int64(2*300*400*64)), tf.float32)
sess.run([test_1, test_2, test_3])
```

This is **not** a error in `tf.cast`.

Comment: To clarify: Although (in Python3) the maximum value of an integer is unbounded (i.e., only bounded by `sys.maxsize`), the call of tf.square() uses internally a numpy data type. Numpy per default uses still 32-bit integers, which have a lower maximum value. As @Patwie pointed out, this is too small to handle the result.